# Negative lookbehind in regex

Tags: regex, perl, negative-lookbehind

*(Note: not a duplicate of [Why can't you use repetition quantifiers in zero-width look behind assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964362/why-cant-you-use-repetition-quantifiers-in-zero-width-look-behind-assertions); see end of post.)*

I'm trying to write a `grep -P` (Perl) regex that matches B, when it is not preceded by A -- regardless of whether there is intervening whitespace.

So, I tried this negative lookbehind, and tested it in regex101.com:

```
(?<!A)\s*B
```

This causes "AB" not to be matched, which is good, but "A B" does result in a match, which is not what I want.

I am not exactly sure why this is. It has something to do with the fact that \s* matches the empty string "", and you can say that there are, as such, infinity matches of \s* between A and B. But why does this affect "A B" but not "AB"?

Is the following regex a proper solution, and if so, why exactly does it fix the problem?

```
(?<![A\s])\s*B
```

I posted this before and it was incorrectly marked as a duplicate question. The variable-length thing I'm looking for is part of the match, not part of the negative lookbehind itself -- so this quite different from the other question. Yes, I could put the \s* inside the negative lookbehind, but I haven't done so (and doing so is not supported, as the other question explains). Also, I am particularly interested in **why the alternate regex I post above works**, since I know it works but I'm not exactly sure why. The other question did not help answer that.

Comment: You could also use `/[^A\s]\s*B/`

Comment: Good point. In my real use case though, A and B are both words rather than just characters.

Comment: `(?<![A\s])\s*B` Not really a good way to do this. One reason is the humungous backtracking going on. Maybe there will come a day when you care more about performance over substance. Since you're using Perl, leverage it's verbs. `(?:A\s*B(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|B)`

Comment: Comparison `Regex1:   (?<![A\s])\s*B Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 ) Matches found per iteration:   1 Elapsed Time:    0.53 s,   530.18 ms,   530185 µs Regex2:   (?:A\s*B(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|B) Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 ) Matches found per iteration:   1 Elapsed Time:    0.18 s,   180.07 ms,   180073 µs`

Comment: @sln: the special verbs are particularly useful since they can be used when A and B are whole words rather than just characters.

Comment: @ikegami: Good catch, since without the `^|` option, `[^A\s]\s*B`  fails to match either "B" or " B".

Comment: @wdep1, I had failed to noticed the first two comments. Deleteing.

Comment: My bad for not specifying that they were whole words to begin with. Still useful info to have. For reference, ikegami noted that if A and B *are* just characters and not words, `[^A\s]\s*B` has problems as described, which `(?:^|[^A\s])\s*B` fixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But why does this affect "A B" but not "AB"?

Regexes match at a *position*, which it is helpful to think of as being between characters. In "A B" there is a position (after the space and before the B) where `(?<!A)` succeeds (because there isn't an A immediately preceding; there's a space instead), and `\s*B` succeeds (`\s*` matches the empty string, and `B` matches B), so the entire pattern succeeds.

In "AB" there is no such position. The only place where `\s*B` can match (immediately before the B), is also immediately after the A, so `(?<!A)` cannot succeed. There are no positions that satisfy both, so the pattern as a whole can't succeed.

> Is the following regex a proper solution, and if so, why exactly does it fix the problem?
>
> `(?<![A\s])\s*B`

This works because `(?<![A\s])` will not succeed immediately after an A *or* after a space. So now the lookbehind forbids any match position that has spaces before it. If there *are* any spaces before the B, they have to be consumed by the `\s*` portion of the pattern, and the match position must be before them. If that position *also* doesn't have an A before it, the lookbehind can succeed and the pattern as a whole can match.

This is a trick that's made possible by the fact that `\s` is a fixed-width pattern that matches at *every* position inside of a non-empty `\s*` match. It can't be extended to the general case of *any* pattern between the (non-)A and the B.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Re: your first point: It took me a minute to realize that "so (?<!A) cannot match" means that the negative lookbehind recognizes A successfully, and says that the pattern match against the whole string fails as a result of the negative lookbehind taking effect.

Comment: To summarize, for anyone who's reading this and confused: For the original regex, "A B" is a tricky case because there's a potential match position before B where the \s* acts like an empty string and there's a preceding space, rather than a preceding A, so the negative lookbehind doesn't forbid a match. To fix this, the altered regex makes sure that only match positions not directly after spaces can be considered.

Comment: @wdep1 valid point! I changed "match" to "succeed" which is hopefully clearer (a negative lookaround succeeds by not matching anything).