# Find multiply groups matching in specific substring

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to catch bold values in the string below that starts with "need" word, while words in other string that starts from "skip" and "ignored" must be ignored. I tried the pattern

`need.+?(:"(?'index'\w+)"[,}])`

but it found only first(ephasised) value. How I can get needed result using RegEx only?

"skip" : {"A":"ABCD123","B":"ABCD1234","C":"ABCD1235"}

"need" : {"A":"***ZABCD123***","B":"**ZABCD1234**","C":"**ZABCD1235**"}

"ignore" : {"A":"SABCD123","B":"SABCD1234","C":"SABCD1235"}

Comment: Looks like JSON. You should parse it and work with it from there.

Comment: I need to use only RegEx

Comment: Why? That's silly. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: I'd like to know whether such issue can be resolved with RegEx or not. I'm not interesting with another solutions, because I'm learning RE and like to know its possibilities. Json here just as example to provide main idea.

Comment: What's the difference between "skip" and "ignore"

Comment: @managerger: You should rewrite the question then, since JSON should not be parsed with regex, in C#, there is JSON.net for it. What you ask is possible, but only if the text you are searching for is between clear non-ambiguous non-identical boundaries.

Comment: The simplest way if you don't need too much structure is this `"need"\s*:\s*\{(?:[^{}]*?"(ZABCD[^"]*)")+[^{}]*?\}` then get the group 1 CaptureCollections for the list. I could post the actual code in an answer if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going find `need` and group what we find into [Named Match Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#named_matched_subexpression) =>  [Captures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx). There will be two groups, one named `Index` which holds the `A | B | C` and then one named `Data`.

The match will hold our data which will look like this:

[image]

From there we will join them into a dictionary:

[image]

Here is the code to do that magic:

```
string data =
@"""skip"" : {""A"":""ABCD123"",""B"":""ABCD1234"",""C"":""ABCD1235""}
""need"" : {""A"":""ZABCD123"",""B"":""ZABCD1234"",""C"":""ZABCD1235""}
""ignore"" : {""A"":""SABCD123"",""B"":""SABCD1234"",""C"":""SABCD1235""}";

string pattern = @"
\x22need\x22\s *:\s *{   # Find need
(                        # Beginning of Captures
   \x22                     #  Quote is \x22
   (?<Index>[^\x22] +)      # A into index.
   \x22\:\x22               # ':'
   (?<Data>[^\x22] +)       # 'Z...' Data
   \x22,?                   # ',(maybe)
)+                       # End of 1 to many Captures";


var mt = Regex.Match(data, 
                     pattern, 
                     RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

// Get the data capture into a List<string>.
var captureData = mt.Groups["Data"].Captures.OfType<Capture>()
                                            .Select(c => c.Value).ToList();

// Join the index capture data and project it into a dictionary.
var asDictionary = mt.Groups["Index"]
                     .Captures.OfType<Capture>()
                     .Select((cp, iIndex) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>
                                                 (cp.Value, captureData[iIndex]) )
                     .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value );
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Marked as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If number of fields is fixed - you can code it like:

```
^"need"\s*:\s*{"A":"(\w+)","B":"(\w+)","C":"(\w+)"}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EORwPg/1)

If tags would be *after* values - like that:

> {"A":"ABCD123","B":"ABCD1234","C":"ABCD1235"} : "skip"
>   {"A":"ZABCD123","B":"ZABCD1234","C":"ZABCD1235"} : "need"
>   {"A":"SABCD123","B":"SABCD1234","C":"SABCD1235"} : "ignore"

Then you could employ *infinite positive look ahead* with

```
"\w+?":"(\w+?)"(?=.*"need")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GS3CGQ/1)

But *infinite positive look behind's* [are prohibited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964362/why-cant-you-use-repetition-quantifiers-in-zero-width-look-behind-assertions) in PCRE. (prohibited use of `*+` operators in look behind's syntax). So not very useful in your situation

Comment: Number of fields isn't fixed. So, the next answer is most appropriate. It allows to find an arbitrary quantity of values. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

[You can't capture a dynamically set number of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp/3537914#3537914), so I'd run something like this regex

```
"need".*{.*,?".*?":(".+?").*}
```

[[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lUE1uQ/1)]

with a 'match_all' function, or use Agnius' suggestion