# Do not match if there is more than one of a single character

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex that validates any text with no dots or any text ending with `.gt` or `.lt`. Any text with more that one dot should also be invalid.

```
anytext // valid
anytext.gt // valid
anytext.lt // valid
anytext.xx // invalid
anytext.xx.gt // invalid
```

I've created this: `^.*(\.(gt|lt)|(?<!\..*))$`

It works well except by the fact that it accepts more than 1 dot, so something like `foo.bar.gt` is being validated and should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match one or more word characters `\w+` or specify in a character class what you want to match and end with an optional dot followed by gt or lt:

[`^\w+(?:\.[gl]t)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/PDcp8E/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\w+` One or more [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.[gl]t` Match a dot and either `g` or `l` followed by `t`
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
^[^.\n]+(\.(gt|lt))?$
```

Key differences to your solution:

- Instead of the "initial" `.` I used `[^.\n]` - any character
  other than a dot or a newline.
- As a quantifier following it I used `+`, to accept only non-empty content.
- I dropped the second alternative (`(?<!\..*)`) and the preceding `|`.
- After the capturing group I added `?`, because the `.lt` or `.gt`
  suffix is optional.

One more remark: In negative lookbehind you can not use quantifiers
(you tried `.*`).

Comment: Are you sure your remark is correct? [`Why can't you use repetition quantifiers in zero-width look behind assertions
`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964362/why-cant-you-use-repetition-quantifiers-in-zero-width-look-behind-assertions/24591663)

Comment: His remark is correct about *lookbehind*, yes - assuming we're talking about Java or PCRE (but not .Net)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is straightforward:

```
^[^.]+(\.[gl]t)?$
```

[**See Regex101 demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/Xy6VYN/1).

Comment: You'll probably want to do `^[^.]+?(\.[gl]t)?$` (greedy), otherwise it could capture two lines instead of one.

Comment: The OP did say "any text" ;-)

Comment: It's doubtful line-feeds are considered "text". In fact you only should need to do `^([^.]+\.[gl]t)$`, which would be 24 steps less than your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as that: `^\w+(\.[gl]t){0,1}$`. `\w` will match any string before `.gt` or `.lt`

Comment: That solution looks familiar :-)