# Regex Negative Lookbehind ignored

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

Here is my regex:

```
(?<!PAYROLL)(FIDELITY(?!.*TITLE)(?!.*NATION)|INVEST)(?!.*PAYROLL)
```

Here is my text

```
INCOMING WIRE TRUST GS INVESTMENT 
VANGUARD PAYROLL
PAYROLL FIDELITY
ACH CREDIT FIDELITY INVESTM-FIDELITY
ACH CREDIT FIDELITY INVESTM-FIDELITY
ACH DEBIT FIDELITY 
ACH DEBIT FIDELITY 
ACH CREDIT FIDELITY INVESTM-FIDELITY
```

When running this on http://regexr.com (using the PCRE RegEx Engine), it is matching on `"PAYROLL FIDELITY"`, yet I'm specifying a negative lookbehind to not do that`(?<!PAYROLL)`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: But there is a whitespace, try with `(?<!PAYROLL\s)`, see https://regex101.com/r/MclkGz/1

Comment: Use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) instead - regex seems to work there

Comment: That worked, @WiktorStribiżew, how come I cant use ```.*``` instead of ```\s```?

Comment: It is not possible to use infinite width patterns inside lookbehinds in PCRE regex patterns. You may work around it with `(*SKIP)(*F)`: `\bPAYROLL.*?FIDELITY(*SKIP)(*F)|(FIDELITY(?!.*TITLE)(?!.*NATION)|INVEST)(?!.*PAYROLL)`. See https://regex101.com/r/MclkGz/2

Comment: ah ```*``` A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width, i'll see if i can find a work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<!PAYROLL)` negative lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded with `PAYROLL` char sequence. In the `PAYROLL FIDELITY` string, the `FIDELITY` is not immediately preceded with `PAYROLL`, it is immediately preceded with `PAYROLL` + **space**.

You can solve the current problem in various ways. If you are sure there is always a single whitespace between words in the string (say, it is a tokenized string) add `\s` after `PAYROLL`: `(?<!PAYROLL\s)`.

If there can be one or more whitespaces, the `(?<!PAYROLL\s+)` pattern won't work in PCRE as PCRE lookbehind patterns [must be of fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964362/why-cant-you-use-repetition-quantifiers-in-zero-width-look-behind-assertions). You might match (some) exceptions and skip them using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` PCRE verbs:

```php
PAYROLL\s+FIDELITY(*SKIP)(*F)|(FIDELITY(?!.*TITLE)(?!.*NATION)|INVEST)(?!.*PAYROLL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MclkGz/4). You may even replace `PAYROLL\s+FIDELITY(*SKIP)(*F)` with `PAYROLL.*?FIDELITY(*SKIP)(*F)` or `PAYROLL[\s\S]+?FIDELITY(*SKIP)(*F)` to skip any text chunk from `PAYROLL` till the leftmost `FIDELITY`. `PAYROLL\s+FIDELITY(*SKIP)(*F)` matches `PAYROLL`, one or more whitespaces, `FIDELITY` and then fails the match triggering backtracking, and then the match is skipped and the next match is searched for starting from the index where the failure occurred.